# how do I dynamically render title as component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render, react-native-router-flux

I have a scene:

```
<Scene key="myFeed" component={myFeed} renderTitle={level}/>
```

In which I use the component to display the "title".
This function:

```
const level = () => {
  return (
     <Level/>
  )
}
```

This component:

```
export class Level extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            progressBar: {},
            loading: true,
        };

    }

    connection() {
        myApi.getServer('/user/level/', (data) => {
            this.setState({loading: false, progressBar: data});
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
            this.setState({loading: false});
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View  style={styles.topBarCenterSlider}>
                   <View style={styles.topBarSlider}>
                          <View style={[styles.topBarStatus, {width: this.state.progressBar.level["progress"] + '%' : 0}]}/>
                          </View>
                   </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I need to change the component after the server response.
Help please, and sorry for my English))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you dont invoke "connection()". Put in componentWiLlMount

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.connection();
}
```

Comment: Check this `width: this.state.progressBar.level["progress"] + '%' : 0`. Try change to `width:  this.state.progressBar.level ? this.state.progressBar.level["progress"] + '%' : 0`

Comment: One more question is possible? 
Why the function "connection" is triggered twice?


  componentWillMount() {
        (this.state.loading) ? this.connection() : null;
    }

Comment: I have no idea why  the function "connection" is triggered twice. But you dont need put (this.state.loading) ? this.connection() : null. Cause componentWillMount will trigger only one. See more at docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount